# Google map info window button is not displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

Here i have map markers with info window.in info window i need to add one button .when i click that button it should pass the id value based on marker click can any one help me out i have added my fiddele http://jsfiddle.net/5z86v5ay/5/

```js
//Angular App Module and Controller
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {
var cities = [
    { 
     id:'1',
        city: 'Toronto',
        desc: 'This is the best city in the world!',
        lat: 43.7000,
        long: -79.4000
    },
    {
     id:'2',
        city: 'New York',
        desc: 'This city is aiiiiite!',
        lat: 40.6700,
        long: -73.9400
    },
    {
      id:'3',
        city: 'Chicago',
        desc: 'This is the second best city in the world!',
        lat: 41.8819,
        long: -87.6278
    },
    {
      id:'4',
        city: 'Los Angeles',
        desc: 'This city is live!',
        lat: 34.0500,
        long: -118.2500
    },
    {
      id:'5',
        city: 'Las Vegas',
        desc: 'This city is live!',
        lat: 36.0800,
        long: -115.1522
    }
];

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.city
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.city + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent"><button type="button" value="Get id" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + info.id + ')>get</button></div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
        $scope.markers.push(marker);
    }
    $scope.getid =function(id)
 {
 console.log(id);
 }
    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        createMarker(cities[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }




    $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
        $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      $scope.markers.length = 0;
    }



    $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
       //1.select filtered cities
       var filteredCities;
       var cityDesc = $scope.data.singleSelect;
       if(cityDesc == '0') {
          filteredCities = cities;
       }
       else {
          filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c){
            if(c.desc == cityDesc)
               return c; 
          });
       }  
       //2.update markers on map
       $scope.clearMarkers();
       for (i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
        createMarker(filteredCities[i]);
       }
    }

});
```

```html
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <br><br>
        <label>Filter Marker </label><br>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers()">
            <option value="0">all</option>
            <option value="This is the best city in the world!">This is the best city in the world!</option>
            <option value="This city is aiiiiite">This city is aiiiiite</option>
            <option value="This is the second best city in the world!">This is the second best city in the world!</option>
            <option value="This city is live!">This city is live!</option>
        </select><br>
        <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
            <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the provided example:

1) first one is a typo, missing closing double quote in `ng-click` expression, instead of `ng-click="getid(' + info.id + ')` it shold be `ng-click="getid(' + info.id + ')"`

2)Second one, due to the dynamic nature of `google.maps.InfoWindow`, `content` property needs to be [compiled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) otherwise `ng-click` will not be triggered.

To summarize, you could just replace `createMarker` function with:

```
var createMarker = function (info) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
        title: info.city
    });
    marker.templateContent = '<div><h2>' + marker.title + '</h2><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.city + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent"><button type="button" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + info.id + ')">Book Now</button></div>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var iwTemplate = ($compile(marker.templateContent)($scope));
        infoWindow.setContent(iwTemplate[0]);
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
    });
    $scope.markers.push(marker);
}
```

> Note: It is not recommended to perform DOM manipulation in
>   controller, prefer directive for that purpose. So you could consider to > create a directive for info window

[Modified JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/5z86v5ay/15/)